# getAllBlobs() method deprecated - Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I'm trying to send forms files.
The files are being uploaded, but they are corrupted.
I'm using a method that is deprecated, I would like to know how to solve this problem.

```
function getAttachmentArchive(){
  const totalRange = retriveTotalSubmission();
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1Jf3ikldJoPgaVK-l5Gpo8YFjPmI4q2a2Rq9txNT3g');
  const attachmentArchive =sheet.getRange(`X${totalRange + 1}`);
  console.log(attachmentArchive, 'SEPARAÇÃOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO')
  console.log(attachmentArchive.getValue())
  const folder = attachmentArchive.getValue().split(',');
  let fileId = [];
  let filesBlob = [];
 // console.log(folder)
  for(i=0;folder.length > i;i++){
    let folderId;

    let fetchedBlob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(folder[i].trim()).getBlob()
    
    folderId = folder[i].split('=');

    fetchedBlob.setName(DriveApp.getFileById(folderId[1]).getName())
    let blob = fetchedBlob

    filesBlob.push(blob)
    fileId.push(folderId[1]);
  }

 // console.log(filesBlob, 'file')
  let file = [];
  for(i=0;fileId.length>i;i++){
    file.push(DriveApp.getFileById(fileId[i]));
  }

 const blob = Utilities.zip(filesBlob,'AnexoContasAPagar.zip').getAllBlobs();
 const anexo = Utilities.zip(blob,'Anexo.zip');

 //const anexo = Utilities.zip(filesBlob,'AnexoContasAPagar.zip');

  const attachmentBase64 = Utilities.base64Encode(anexo.getBytes());
  return attachmentBase64;
}
```

if i just remove the getAllBlobs() method the attachment is not sent.

Comment: I think that in the current stage, your showing script still works even when `getAllBlobs()` is used. When I saw your script, it seems that `filesBlob` is zipped as `AnexoContasAPagar.zip` and the zipped file is zipped as `Anexo.zip`. Is this your expected result? I'm worried that this might not be your expected result. First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
const blob = Utilities.zip(filesBlob, 'AnexoContasAPagar.zip');
const blobs = await blob.getBlobs();
```

getBlobs() method returns an array of blobs where each blob in the array represents a file in the zip file.

And after that

```
const anexo = await blobs.zip('Anexo.zip');
```